# Закраска PictureBox из массива ARGB

Tags: c#, массивы, picturebox

Здравствуйте!
Помогите разобраться, вот, имею код:

```
string[] stringArraySplit = (getText[0].Split('s'));


        Bitmap bitmap = PictureBox.Image as Bitmap;
        for (int i = 0; i < PictureBox.Image.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < PictureBox.Image.Height; j++)
            {
                bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.stringArraySplit first to last);
                PictureBox.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

В `getText[0]` имеется каша из пикселей ARGB такого формата

```
255,78,84,80s255,79,85,81s
```

где `s` - разделитель.
Далее, в `stringArraySplit` в каждый индекс записывается значение пикселя и мы имеем массив с пикселями, которые нужно отрисовать в битмапе. 
Далее я указываю в каком порядке отрисовывать пиксели

```
for (int i = 0; i < PictureBox.Image.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < PictureBox.Image.Height; j++)
                {
```

А вот как мне подстроить под этот порядок пиксели из массива не могу понять, допустим:

```
bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Red);
```

Всё работает, пиксели заливаются красным, а как мне вместо красного подсунуть массив, с которого для i, j будут браться пиксели?
Порядок отрисовки пикселей с нулевого индекса и до последнего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну наверное как-то так:

```
string[] stringArraySplit = (getText[0].Split('s'));
var colors = stringArraySplit
        .Select(s => s.Split(','))
        .Select(v => Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(v[0]), int.Parse(v[1]),
                                    int.Parse(v[2]), int.Parse(v[3])))
        .ToList();

int colorIndex = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < PictureBox.Image.Height; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PictureBox.Image.Width; i++)
    {
        bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, colors[colorIndex]);
        colorIndex++;
    }
}
```

(Я переставил циклы по `i` и по `j` местами, так как скорее всего ваши пиксели именно в таком порядке.)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, но прошу прощенья, т.к. я - нуб, у меня красным подчеркнуло вот это:v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3])
                    .ToList(); не может конвертировать стринг в инт, и вот это color[colorIndex]); - не существует в этом контексте, не могли бы Вы сказать, в чём я ошибся?

Comment: @AwesomePhoenix: А, да, это я ошибся. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @AwesomePhoenix: Исправил, пробуйте снова.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь пишет только про ToList() - Color does not contain for ToList.... Name ToList does not exist in the current content...

Comment: @AwesomePhoenix: Сорри, я забыл одну закрывающую скобку после `int.Parse(v[3])`. Добавил её.

Comment: @AwesomePhoenix: И `color` надо заменить на `colors`. Соори за ошибки, писалось на коленке.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает.

Comment: @AwesomePhoenix: Ура! Вот и хорошо, одной проблемой меньше.